# C ignoring incrementation

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, compilation, increment

I tried this but my compiler(Visual Studio 2013) keeps messing up things. 
I have a 9 by 9 matrix indexed from 1. It is 0 at the beginig. And starting from element 1:1 I start incrementing the value in the matrix or incrementing x,y, basically moving to the next matrix element.

However, the program ignores my incrementation and the fact that x,y are initially set to 1. 
Also it ignores a function call.
Code is commented below.

I am sure this is the source I am compiling!
Restarted laptop and Visual Studio but still doesn't work.
Opened new project, same thing.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

unsigned int Matrix[10][10], x, y;

// Ignore this..
int checkLine()
{
    unsigned int i, j, k;
    for (k = 1; k <= 9; k++){
        if (Matrix[k][1] == 0) break;
        for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
                if (Matrix[k][i] == Matrix[k][j] && i!=j)
                    return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

//Ignore this..
int checkColumn()
{
    unsigned int i, j, k;
    for (k = 1; k <= 9; k++){
        if (Matrix[1][k] == 0) break;
        for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
                if (Matrix[i][k] == Matrix[j][k] && i!=j)
                    return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

//Ignore this..
int checkSquare()
{
    unsigned int i, j, k,l,m,n;
    for (m = 1; m <= 7; m = m + 3)
    for (n = 1; n <= 7; n = n + 3)

    for (k = m; k <= m + 2; k++)
    for (l = n; l <= n + 2; l++)
    for (i = m; i <= m + 2; i++)
    for (j = n; j <= n + 2; j++)
        if (Matrix[k][l] == Matrix[i][j] && !(k==i && l==j))
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

void increment()
{
    if (y == 9)
    {
        x++;
        y = 1;
    }
    else y++;
}

void decrement()
{
    if (y == 1)
    {
        x--;
        y = 9;
    }
    else
        y--;
}

void print_Matrix(){
    unsigned int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
        for (j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
            printf("%u ", Matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

//
// MAIN. PROBLEM BELOW
//**
void main()
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i <= 9;i++)
    for (j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
        Matrix[i][j] = 0;

    print_Matrix(); // Function call is ignored here. Don't know why.***

    x = 1; 
    y = 1;
    // X and Y are OBVIOUSLY 1***

    while (x < 10) //Condition OBVIOUSLY true***
    {
        printf("%u, %u", x, y); //Keeps printing 0,3 and eventually 0,2***
        printf("\n");

        Matrix[x][y]++; //Incrementation...*** 

        print_Matrix(); // Always prints a blank Matrix consisting of only 0's***


        if (checkLine() && checkColumn() && checkSquare())
        {
            increment();
        }

        if (Matrix[x][y] == 10){
            Matrix[x][y] = 0;
            decrement();
        }



    }

    print_Matrix();

}
```

Comment: Your example does not even compile as is. And it should be `int main()`.

Comment: How do you know the first function call is "ignored"? That seems impossible from the code given.

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img538/9657/rHcnx9.png

Comment: Printing starts with 0,3 instead of a blank matrix

Comment: So you increase the position [1][1] ten times before calling "decrement()" and turning it back to zero. The decrement call should make Y = 9 and X = 0, so now you're writing on the 0 indexes that you were trying so hard to avoid, but the check functions never take those indexes into account. So I guess your program will be stuck in there forever? Don't blame the compiler..

Comment: I increment with Matrix[x][y]++; and IMEDIATELY print the matrix, and still get only 0's

Comment: Tried on a different computer, same result

Comment: I just ran your code and it does exactly what I just said

Comment: 1. It does not increase shit. At least not here. Everything remains 0. Always.

Comment: But I replaced unsigned int with int and now works, it is buggy, but the incrementation works. I have no idea why it would matter...

Comment: @AlexPop - you might find this interesting (regarding using unsigned for indexing) https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/534769

Comment: @AlexPop The incrementation doesn't work that way either. I've answered why. All I've done was check what happens when you run the code, I still have no idea what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You feel that the `increment` is ignored because the `checkSquare` function is buggy. It never returned 1 and hence the `increment` function was never called.

Comment: For `x=1, y=1`, the instruction `Matrix[x][y]++` is taking effect. But after it became 10, the call to `decrement` function took place in which `x` became 0 and `y` became `9`. But in the `print_matrix` function, you never printed the cells with `x=0`. And in `checkLine`, `checkColumn` and `checkSquare` functions, you were checking for cells with `x>1`.

Comment: You are the second one to say that. On my laptop it doesn't. Unless I replace unsigned int with int... Have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

Your output is a bit confusing since the output of the line

```
printf("%u, %u", x, y);
```

runs into the output of

```
print_Matrix();
```

By adding a newline to the output of the first line, i.e. by using

```
printf("%u, %u\n", x, y);
```

you will notice that at some point `x` gets decremented to `0` and never gets incremented again. Since you never print `Matrix[0][y]`, you never see the non-zero values.

In addition to the change to above `printf`, if you change `print_Matrix` to:

```
void print_Matrix(){
   unsigned int i, j;

   for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
        // ^^^ Use 0 instead of 1
      for (j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
           // ^^^ Use 0 instead of 1
         printf("%u ", Matrix[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
   }
}
```

you will see the non-zero values.

See working code at http://ideone.com/HlQ4xp.

Comment: Nothing of what you say happens to me, unless i replace unsigned int with int... WHY? I do not understand..

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you're incrementing the position marked by x and y, that's position [1][1]. Until it reaches 10 nothing interesting happens, you can actually see the top left corner of the matrix increasign to 10, but then the condition to decrement becomes true and you decrement.

See for yourself (prints),

```
while (x < 10) //Condition OBVIOUSLY true***
{
    printf("%u, %u", x, y); //Keeps printing 0,3 and eventually 0,2***
    printf("\n");

    Matrix[x][y]++; //Incrementation...*** 

    print_Matrix(); // Always prints a blank Matrix consisting of only 0's***


    if (checkLine() && checkColumn() && checkSquare())
    {
        increment();
    }

    if (Matrix[x][y] == 10){
        Matrix[x][y] = 0;
        decrement();
    }

    printf( "Enter to continue\n" );
    getchar();

}
```

It turns Y = 9, X = 0 and the [1][1] position becomes 0, so you see only zeros because you're not printing the zero indexes.

This process repeats until Y = 1 and X = 0, you increase the position until 10 so that the decrement works again.

When Y = 1, X = 0 and position [0][1] is 10, the decrement call will do x--. Since X is an unsigned int, it will underflow and become 4.2 billion something, which is greater than 10 and the loop ends.

What are you trying to achieve here?

---

Edit: Something even more amazing happens when you make x and y ints instead of unsigned ints.

Instead of x underflowing it will become -1. Matrix[-1][9]++ strangely increased x by 1 when I ran the code, so x went back to 0. Which means the program loops forever at this point.

The increment function was never called.

Answer (score 0):

It shows matrix and increment when tested online, here are results

1) for C compiler

http://ideone.com/KRLO8w

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

unsigned int Matrix[10][10], x, y;

// Ignore this..
int checkLine()
{
    unsigned int i, j, k;
    for (k = 1; k <= 9; k++){
        if (Matrix[k][1] == 0) break;
        for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
                if (Matrix[k][i] == Matrix[k][j] && i!=j)
                    return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

//Ignore this..
int checkColumn()
{
    unsigned int i, j, k;
    for (k = 1; k <= 9; k++){
        if (Matrix[1][k] == 0) break;
        for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
                if (Matrix[i][k] == Matrix[j][k] && i!=j)
                    return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

//Ignore this..
int checkSquare()
{
    unsigned int i, j, k,l,m,n;
    for (m = 1; m <= 7; m = m + 3)
    for (n = 1; n <= 7; n = n + 3)

    for (k = m; k <= m + 2; k++)
    for (l = n; l <= n + 2; l++)
    for (i = m; i <= m + 2; i++)
    for (j = n; j <= n + 2; j++)
        if (Matrix[k][l] == Matrix[i][j] && !(k==i && l==j))
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

void increment()
{
    if (y == 9)
    {
        x++;
        y = 1;
    }
    else y++;
}

void decrement()
{
    if (y == 1)
    {
        x--;
        y = 9;
    }
    else
        y--;
}

void print_Matrix(){
    unsigned int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
        for (j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
            printf("%u ", Matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

//
// MAIN. PROBLEM BELOW
//**
void main()
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i <= 9;i++)
    for (j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
        Matrix[i][j] = 0;

    print_Matrix(); // Function call is ignored here. Don't know why.***

    x = 1; 
    y = 1;
    // X and Y are OBVIOUSLY 1***

    while (x < 10) //Condition OBVIOUSLY true***
    {
        printf("%u, %u", x, y); //Keeps printing 0,3 and eventually 0,2***
        printf("\n");

        Matrix[x][y]++; //Incrementation...*** 

        print_Matrix(); // Always prints a blank Matrix consisting of only 0's***


        if (checkLine() && checkColumn() && checkSquare())
        {
            increment();
        }

        if (Matrix[x][y] == 10){
            Matrix[x][y] = 0;
            decrement();
        }



    }

    print_Matrix();

}
```

2) for c++ compiler C++ 4.9.2 (changed return type of main to int)

http://ideone.com/Ey5nG1

In your image starting value of 0, 3 is due to buffer limit of command prompt. As the program never ends, so it terminates abruptly and latest few bytes are stored in buffer and is only shown that much. To see complete output redirect it to a file and open it.